# Contact Form 7 Date in UK Format

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I have been trying to get the date to show up in the UK format

This is the code i use to show the date picker on the website

```
<p>Lesson Start Date <span>[date date-501 _format_date-501 "D, d M y"]</span> </p>
```

This is the code i use in the mail section to print the info out in the email

```
<strong>Lesson Start Date:</strong> [date-501]
```

however cant get it to work.

Comment: You have a lot of questions with answers that you haven't selected a correct answer for. Please go through them, and select answers as "correct" where they have proven useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have things switched around. The `[_format_{field name} "{date format}"]` paradigm is for the mail field, not the form field. This means that your mail field should be:

```
[_format_date-501 "D, d M y"]
```

You should remove the `_format` from the date field in your form:

```
<p>Lesson Start Date <span>[date date-501]</span> </p>
```

Read more about date formatting [in the docs](http://contactform7.com/date-field/).